# How to show that Span $(x) \subseteq W_1 + W_2 ?$

Tags: linear-algebra

If  $W_1 + W_2$ are finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space , then $W_1 + W_2$ is finite  -dimensional and $\dim(W_1 + W_2)= \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - \dim (W_1 \cap W_2)$

Proof :

let $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$  be  basis for  $W_1 \cap W_2$

let $a= b+c \in W_1 +W_2$  where $b \in W_1$  and  $c \in W_2$

let  $x$  is  a basis for  $W_1 +  W_2$ where $ x= \{a_1,a_2 ,...., a_k ,b_1,b_2 ,.....,b_m,c_1,c_2,.....,c_p\}$

Now to prove this theorem two condition must be satisfied given below

$1.$ $x$ is linearly independent

$2$. Span $(x)= W_1 + W_2$

I can easily proved the first condition

But im stuck in condition $2$
For condition $(2)$ we can write  $x= \underbrace{(x_1a_1+ ....+x_ka_k + y_1b_1+.....+y_mb_m)}_{W_1} + \underbrace{(z_1a_1+ ...+z_ka_k+ t_1c_1+...+t_pc_p)}_{W_2}$

$x= (( x_1 +z_1)a_1 +....+(x_k+z_k)a_k + y_1b_1 +....+y_mb_m + t_1c_1 +....+t_pc_p)$

This implies that $W_1 + W_2 \subseteq $Span $(  x)$

But here im confusing that

How to show that Span $(x) \subseteq W_1 + W_2 ?$

Comment: What do you mean by "let $a=b+c\in W_1+W_2$"? What are the $b_i$ and $c_i$ in "$x= \{ … \}$"?. Why do you write "let $x$ be a basis" when that's what you are trying to prove?

Comment: The fact that $\operatorname{span}(x)\subseteq W_1+W_2$ is trivial since all elements of $x$ are elements of $W_1$ or $W_2$, aren't they?

Comment: You seem to use $x$ both as a symbol for a set of vectors and as a symbol for a vector itself. Avoid using reusing symbols and especially reusing them for different types of objects.

Comment: that  is talking about vector @Christoph im sorry for that  i used the word let $x$ be basis ..that my bad thinking

Comment: What is $a$? What are $b_1,\dots,b_m$ and $c_1,\dots,c_p$? What are $x_1,\dots,x_k,y_1,\dots,y_m,z_1,\dots,z_k,t_1,\dots,t_p$? You have to actually say what things are in your proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Things are a bit confused. Let $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ be a basis of $W_1\cap W_2$ and prolonge it in a basis of $W_1$ and a basis of $W_2$, i.e. take $\{u_1,...,u_n,v_1,...,v_k\}$ being a basis of $W_1$ and $\{u_1,...,u_n,w_1,...,w_p\}$ being a basis of $W_2$.

Now, prove that $\{u_1,...,u_n,v_1,...,v_k,w_1,...,w_p\}$ is a basis of $W_1+W_2$, and thus $$\dim(W_1+W_2)=n+k+p=\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)-\dim(W_1\cap W_2).$$

Comment: okk  this is more  easier as compare to my given proof   @Surb ....Pliz tell me whether my proof is correct  or not ...or im going in wrong way?

Comment: It's not going well. The fact that $\mathcal B=\{u_1,...,u_n,v_1,...,v_k,w_1,...w_p\}$ generate $W_1+W_2$ is clear. You have to prove the $\mathcal B$ is free. First of all prove that, $v_i\notin W_2$ and $w_i\notin W_1$ for all $i$. Then suppose it's not free, and try to get a contradiction. @jasmine

Comment: ok got its thanks u @Surb